# Howto show tables in Man pages converted to html?

Tags: man

I use my browser for opening man pages, converted on the fly to HTML pages. This works quite well, except tables aren't shown. Instead I see an Alt-text like `<p align="center"><font color="#000000"><b><img src="grohtml-199582.png" alt="Image grohtml-199582.png"></b></font></p>` and the image is actually not found.

I use following environment variables:

```
MANOPT='--encoding=UTF-8 -Txhtml --preprocessor=tpr --html'
MANLESS='$MAN_PN$-i -J -Q -R -x4'
BROWSER='firefox %s:lynx %s'
```

If I set `MANOPT` to an empty string the man page with nice drawn tables is shown in my terminal.

Any advice?

Comment: man2html is a perl script, which is "available", like many other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groff has incomplete support for converting manual pages to html, in particular **tables**.  groff generates an image file which is *clipped* from its **`pdf`**-output code.  Sometimes the clipping is poor (trimming parts of the text), and other times it dumps core.

You *might* find that your image files were written to a temporary directory (rather than to the location where your webpage resides).  If they are not in the same directory as the webpage *when* the browser loads the page, it will not find the images.

Additionally, it's not possible to search for text in those tables, defeating the purpose of *making* a table.

After several years of working around groff's problems, I converted all of my manual/html to use [`man2html`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/man2html.html).   See for example, [xterm's manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html).

Comment: Even man2html isn't perfect as it can't properly parse tables, but uses the ascii/utf8 representation. This looks only good with a monospace font. Also sometimes this breaks (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/systemd.service.5.html).

Comment: Sure - it uses a monospace font because it's a post-processor for nroff.  As I'm using it, I'm limiting that to ASCII (to simplify parsing web-links), but groff does use UTF-8 line-drawing in a Unicode locale, so man2html could be modified to handle that.  But proportional fonts - no, because nroff doesn't do anything else.